# JavaFX -- get the coordinates of a link in the WebView

Tags: html, webview, hyperlink, javafx, coordinates

In JavaFX how would I go about getting the WebView rectangle coordinates for a given element in the DOM?

For example, how can I get the rectangle coordinates for a given HTML A tag ... that is, the X/Y coordinates for the exact position of the A Tag text in the WebView as it appears to the user once all the HTML/CSS has been rendered?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10897011) may be helpful.