# Drawing on top of WebView JavaFx

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, javafx-2

I'm creating a Java Application in which i have to

- Show google maps 

- be able to draw a rectangle at a certain point on the map, and it should move along with the map upon dragging the map. 

- Another rectangle to be drawn, which will move just like the first rectangle upon dragging the map, BUT will have joystick controls in java application to be able to move independant of map as well.

So far:

- Showing google maps in a webview using JavaFx.

**UPDATE**

 - Able to add an overlay rectangle to the map using from here: [How to make an overlay on top of JavaFX 2 webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894903/how-to-make-an-overlay-on-top-of-javafx-2-webview/) 

 But the map is no longer taking touches (or has ceased to be draggable).[image]

Comment: have you tried using `StackPane`?
I am sure using `stackpane` and the `binding` functionality you will be able to achieve what you are looking for !

Comment: I haven't, but i'll search and check.
Thanks

Comment: Sergey: please see update