# How to implement ' open link in new tab' functionality in web view javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have written a tabbed browser in javafx using fxml. I want a context menu to appear when I right click the hyperlink appearing in the webpage. The context menu should have 'open link in new tab' as menu item. On clicking this menu item, the relevant url should open in new tab, as happens other in browsers. Nowhere I found the desired code to achieve this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Juste a question, (do not take it badly) but did you try something?

Comment: Yes I have. Unfortunately the source code is too large, it includes fxml and css files, that's why I avoided to put it here. I am trying for many days and now I am stuck on this issue. I expect help from users. Please help.

Comment: I am waiting for an answer.

Comment: Here's a nudge in the right direction: [Custom Web Browser with New Tab Functionality: JavaFX, WebView and TabPane](http://alokomkar.blogspot.ca/2013/07/custom-web-browser-with-new-tab.html)

Comment: I have already tried the tutorial and my source code owes very much to this tutorial. But I have moved a little ahead of this stage. What I want now is when I right-click on any hyperlink appearing in webpage, a context menu saying "Open link in new tab" should appear and clicking on that menu item should lead me to a new webpage in another tab. This feature is common in all known web browsers like IE, FireFox, Chrome, Opera &c.

Comment: I found [this](http://blogs.kiyut.com/tonny/2013/07/30/javafx-webview-addhyperlinklistener/), which is an interesting bit of code (although it took a bit of editing to compile on my computer). What I found out is that although it is possible to add a listener to the "click", "mousedown" and "mouseover" events, it looks like JavaFX filters out the "contextmenu" event (the right-click event). And there is no way to find which button generated the event, since `org.w3c.dom.events.Event` only has a part of the standard javascript API.

Comment: I tried looking for `WebView`'s `ContextMenu` in the source code, thinking that I could extend `WebView` and give it a custom `ContextMenu`, since it seems that it already has the value of the clicked link, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Last piece of info: it looks like `WebView` blocks all right-clicks (tested with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/vTZZ5/), with `contextMenuEnabledProperty` enabled and disabled). Knowing this, the only way left would be to add a listener to the `WebView` and map the mouse coordinates to coordinates of the various links in the web page ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894903/how-to-make-an-overlay-on-top-of-javafx-2-webview) might be helpful).